# AngularJS - Mock $window in unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am trying to mock `$window` object with this:

```
var mock$window = {
    scrollTop : 150,
    height : 600
};
$provide.value('$window', mock$window);
```

When I run the test, I am able to get `$window.scrollTop()` value, but when I try with `$window.height()`, I get the error of `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'height' in undefined`.

What is the proper way to mock `$windows` object?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how $window is used and what you want to test. In a controller where you have it as dependency you can do something like

```
var $scope;
var mockWindow = {...};
beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_, _$controller_) {
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    _$controller_('MainCtrl', {$window: mockWindow});
}));
```

You defined mock$window as Object with keys and integer values but called functions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. How 'bout if my code is in directive. How can that be done?

Comment: If it is in the controller of the directive, you can test only the controller, if in the link-function, you can use your $provide. But then you have to define the mock with functions for scrollToTop() and height()